# SPFX webpart shows at r is not a constructor error randomly

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

[image]

I frequently get the above error in my dashboard page which consist of few spfx webparts. This error appears randomly 1 in 10 times, The spfx webparts do not consume any pnp framework or jquery nor it references any js from CDN. We also have an application customizer extension for the site collection which also uses custom js libraries from the sharepoint directories.

Its been a month and we are not able to figure out what is this akamai error Any pointers on why this error is occuring will be highly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is some uncaught TypeError, if it does not change the functionality, I would ignore it and post it on MSFT forums to report a bug.

Comment: i think i should do the same

Comment: Do you have the link? as to where to post